# Get json for the top 1000 submissions on a subreddit

Tags: json, api, reddit

How to get the json response from reddit for the 1000 top submissions to a particular subreddit?
For now it is showing only the first 100 submissions I guess.
code:

`http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/top.json?limit=100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [reddit API docs](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_top) for the `top` submissions on a subreddit:

> ### limit
>
> the maximum number of items desired (default: 25, maximum: 100)

Comment: So is there anyway to get past the 100 limit? I mean something like next page or something like that?

Comment: @defiant Pass the `after` or `before` arguments.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am sorry, but I couldn't find a way to include those arguments in the URL. Could you please link to me an example code which uses the after/before arguments?

Comment: @defiant those arguments are the data in the POST/GET request you make.